# webpack. Сборка JS

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel

С webpack знаком не так давно, возникло несколько проблем и основная из них - не собираются строчные функции и простые функции.

То есть, у меня есть JS код, который по клику выводит alert:

```js
const authPost = function authPost() {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

Либо же просто функция:

```js
function authPost() {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

Суть в том, что веб-пак обрезает функцию и оставляет лишь alert, из-за чего невозможно вызвать функцию и alert срабатывает при загрузке страницы.

Как это можно исправить, чтобы веб пак корректно собирал JS?
Мой конфиг выглядит вот так:

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const path = require('path')

const dir = 'exp'

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './webpack/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, dir),
        filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: devMode ? 'css/[name].css' : 'css/[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: devMode ? 'css/[id].css' : 'css/[id].[hash].css',
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [{
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
            },{

            }


        ],
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуй сам же и отвечу, если у кого то в будущем возникнут вопросы. Долго искал решение, но лишь спустя час после публикации без ответов нашел решение, пусть и не совсем корректное.

По onclick() не удавалось вызывать функцию, не срабатывало и windows.[nameFunction]
Получилось застаивть работать windows. , если подключить файл с функцией простым import в app.js webpack'a.

JS-код:

```
    window.authPost = function () {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```